# How can i clean Maven plugin bindings?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I want to clear all plugin bindings from default Maven lifecycle. And manually set, only plugins i need. Is it possible ?

Comment: Could you please describe, what you are planning to do with that "empty" lifecycle? Two ideas: 1. Use packaging POM, this has very few attached plugins. 2. Write your own lifecycle.

Comment: Most important the question: "empty" life cycle why?

Comment: I need empty lifecycle, because i want to define only plugins i need. And i don't want to unbind all plugins useless to me, such as Jar-plugin, manually in build-tag section. Because, for example i use shade, and maven generates 2 Jar's. So, i looking for best practice do disable all them at once and add only plugins i need.

Comment: This is not how Maven works. If you are really so dissatisfied with the default lifecycle, you need to write your own lifecycle. But for most use cases, the default lifecycle is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

The `<packaging>` element in the POM determines the [Build Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

Check the [Default Lifecycle Bindings - Packaging `pom`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#default-lifecycle-bindings-packaging-pom) section of that page - `pom` packaging binds only `install` and `deploy` plugins by default.

Start with `pom` packaging and add whatever plugins you need.

**Don't forget** to use something like [build-helper:attach-artifact from Build Helper Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html) to attach the build artifact(s), only the POM will be installed/deployed otherwise.